# Bound an integral by the $L^2$ and $L^\infty$ norms

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

I am reading a book about Euler equation and at some point we aim an extension criterion and I struggle with a point in the proof. At some point we reach the following integral
$$A \equiv\int_{|y| \ge \delta} \frac{|u (x + y)|}{|y|^3} dy$$
and the author claims that, for $u \in C^0([0,T); H^s(\mathbb R^3))$ ($s > d/2 + 1 = 5/2$, $d$ is the dimension) a strong solution of the 3D Euler equations,
$$A \le C(|\log \delta| \|u\|_{L^\infty} + \|u\|_{L^2}).$$
Note that $H^s$ embed in $L^\infty$ so that the norms above are well-defined.

I really don't get he gets this inequality. This $\log \delta $ seems to come from use of the polar coordinates, so that
$$A \le C\|u\|_{L^\infty} \int_{\delta}^\infty \frac{1}{r}dr = C\|u\|_{L^\infty}(\log (\infty) - \log \delta).$$
But how am I supposed to get rid of this $\log \infty$ and from where comes from this $L^2$-norm ?

Comment: Split into the integral for $|y|>1$ and $\delta<|y|<1$. For the first integral, you use the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, as $u\in L^2$ and $\mathbf 1_{|y|>1}(y)|y|^{-3}$ is in $L^2$ as well. For the second integral, you use the estimate you wrote, but now you have $\log(1)$ instead of $\log(\infty)$. Putting these two bounds together, you get the above estimate

Comment: P.s., just in case you missed it, check out the blog of Terence Tao, he has very nice posts on Navier-Stokes and Euler, the Beale-Kato-Majda criterion, …

Comment: Ok nice, thanks a lot! You can put your comment as an answer if you want, I'll accept it